# Form fields for ModelForm with inherited models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a abstract model that defines some fields, and other models that inherited from it.  And if i define a form for this model, base fields not defined and i cannot use it in form.

If i specify it with fields i get this error:

Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (created_at, updated_at) specified for Reseller

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in **new**, line 215

Here my code:

`class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True`

class Reseller(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255, unique=True)

class ResellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reseller
        fields = ('name','created_at','updated_at')

UPD

Its clearly reproduceble with new empty project with this three classes. Its failing on form import

```
 from jjj.forms import ResellerForm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\ShapeR\PycharmProjects\djt\jjj\forms.py", line 4, in 
    class ResellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 214, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
FieldError: Unknown field(s) (created_at, updated_at) specified for Reseller
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

[**`http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable)

> Field.editable
>
> If False, the field will not be
>   editable in the admin or via forms
>   automatically generated from the model
>   class. Default is True.

*also*

> Note
>
> As currently implemented, setting
>   auto_now or auto_now_add to True will
>   cause the field to have editable=False
>   and blank=True set.

Comment: Yes, that was a issue. Its not clear from documentation for me that not editable equals not rendered/accesible at all.

Comment: so have do you get around this if you want to display the fields?  I tried adding editable=False while auto_now was set to True and get the same error.. Would you add it outside of the form and in the template context?

Answer (score 0):

If your indentation matches the excerpt above, then you may need to [properly nest](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) that `Meta` subclass inside `BaseModel`. Otherwise, django will try doing [multi-table inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)--but that should still work with what you're trying to do (unless you have a non-standard setup, e.g. django-nonrel).

What code is triggering this exception, just importing the module?

Comment: In code indentation is fine, just didn`t notice that pasted it with error here. And yes, just importing module triggers error

Comment: And i have i normal setup, with django 1.3